# Why does this function type not resolve correctly?

Tags: typescript, generics

```ts
type OnlyFunction<T> = T extends (...a: any[]) => any ? T : never;

function t1<T extends (...a: any[]) => any>(p: OnlyFunction<T>): ReturnType<T> {
  return p();
}

function t2<T extends (...a: any[]) => any>(): ReturnType<T> {
  return t1<T>(() => "ok"); // Error Argument of type '() => string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OnlyFunction<T>'.
}
```

I was expecting not to get any errors cause T is a callable.

Comment: Please read [ask] and write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you've made `t2` generic for absolutely no reason. The hard-coded function you're passing to `t1` is a specialised `OnlyFunction` which doesn't match the `T` in `t1<T>(...)`

All you need is this...

```ts
function t2() {
  return t1(() => "ok");
}
```